# How can i fix this error with this php?

Tags: php, function, foreach

I have a problem with my code, when I try to use public function setDatos($aDatosPro){

I have `controllerProyectos.php` :

```
<?php
require "dao/daoProyectos.php"; 
class NombreProyecto {

    public function getProyectos() {

           $aTransfer = new daoProyectos();
           $this->setDatos($aTransfer);

    }

    public function setDatos($aDatosPro){

    $obj = $aDatosPro->resultSelect();

    foreach($this->$obj as $sKey=>$oValue){             
            $list[] = array('Id' => $oValue->getId(),'nombre_proyecto' =>$oValue->getNombreProyecto()/*,'state' =>$oValue->getState()*/);
    }
    return $list;

    }
}
?>
```

And I have this error :

> exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Object of class daoProyectos could not be converted to string' in /var/www/html/PROJECTS/dailytasks/controller/controllerProyectos.php:17

`dao/daoProyectos.php` :

```
<?php
require "transferDao/daoTransferProyectos.php";
class daoProyectos{
private function sqlConnection(){

        try {

            $servername = "localhost"; 
            $username = "root";
            $password = "123asd";
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=bd_actividades", $username, $password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
            return $conn;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }   
 public function resultSelect(){

            $aObjects=array();

            $db = $this->sqlConnection();
            $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT pro_id, pro_nombre FROM act_proyecto");
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

            foreach ($result as $row) {
            $aTransfer = new daoTransferProyectos();
            $aTransfer->setId($row['pro_id']);
            $aTransfer->setNombreProyecto($row['pro_nombre']);
            $aObjects[]=$aTransfer;
            }
            return $aObjects;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: post code of `/controllerProyectos.php` because the error points to this file.

Comment: I edit , that is controllerProyectos.php

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez i dont know where is my head.. sorry , I edit, is "public function setDatos($aDatosPro)"

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez I edit and add with daoProyectos.php

Comment: I need = daoTransferProyectos.php . I cannot run your code without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look more carefully here;

```
public function setDatos($aDatosPro){

    $obj = $aDatosPro->resultSelect();

    foreach($this->$obj as $sKey=>$oValue){
```

You are setting the resultSelect return value to $obj (local var) but doing a foreach on $this->obj which is a property of the object you haven't yet set.

Try changing it to;

```
public function setDatos($aDatosPro){

    $this->obj = $aDatosPro->resultSelect();

    foreach($this->$obj as $sKey=>$oValue){
```

or take out the var completely as follows;

```
public function setDatos($aDatosPro){

    foreach($aDatosPro->resultSelect() as $sKey=>$oValue){
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I did  foreach($aDatosPro->resultSelect() as $sKey=>$oValue){ and i don't have any error , thank you